# iOS Swift 2.0: Use of unsolved identifier 'UITableviewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, uitableview

I was following a coding tutorial of making a simple app, everything looked and worked okay at first but after a while I ran into an error says:

```
use of unresolved identifier 'UITableViewCell'.
```

The tutorial's code worked fine in its video and I wrote the exact same code however it was an error on my computer. I guess it's the matter of different versions of Xcode.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        **let cell = UITableviewCell()**
        *//Where the error message is at. //*

        return cell

    }


}
```

The error message is at the line:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
```

Comment: Well what you have posted contradicts itself. You have posted both UITableviewCell() and UITableViewCell. Only one is correct, and there also lies the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on the answer posted by Stefan Salatic but you have to indeed use dequeable cells but to add to that, you should not forget to set the identifier in the main.storyboard to the CellIdentifier you used to create dequeable cell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

In the storyboard go to the TableViewController -> Attribute Inspector -> Identifier and set it to:

```
Identifier
```

If you have an array of data you can fill the cell using:

```
cell!.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should dequeue UITableViewCells. Something like this

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

You want to reuse cells, not create a new one each time. This is the preferred way of doing it.